# How can i ReactDOM.render() multiple react elements into a node without them killing each other?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I use `ReactDOM.render()` a few times, it kills the other elements in the node.
How can I render multiple react elements into a node without them killing each other?

Comment: You should be rendering the top level component which encapsulates any further components.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

A single DOM node can be host to a single React root. Either

- add new DOM nodes to that parent node to host multiple React roots, or
- make the single component you mount something where you can add more components in (in e.g. a `<>` fragment).